# Redirect without change URL

Tags: iis, url, redirect, url-rewriting

is it possible to redirect an URL **www.siteA.com** to **www.site2.com/Default.aspx?SiteSource=siteA** without changing the browser's URL?

Similarly, accessing **www.siteA.com/Page2.aspx** will redirect to the **www.site2.com/Page2.aspx?SiteSource=siteA**

Comment: Are these both on the same webserver? what software is said server running?

Comment: The main page redirect is simple, the problem is the behavior as for what to do with pages within folders like 'www.siteA.com/folder/page2.aspx'

Comment: Yes, the websites are running on IIS 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use mod_proxy (or similar functionality for a different web server) so that the page your server serves is the same as the remote page. But this has some security and performance implications (you're letting the client make your server do arbitrary work copying data across the network from the remote server).

Comment: Search for mod_proxy i found ISAPI Filter. Url: http://blogs.msdn.com/david.wang/archive/2005/08/01/HOWTO_Common_URL_Redirection_Techniques_for_IIS_Summary.aspx

maybe ISAPI can resolve, i´ll try..

Answer (score 1):

server.transfer
if on same server

Comment: *@Daniel Schmitz:* Have you tried? My experience is that `Server.Transfer` does not change the url in browser. In my case this was not desirable...

Answer (score 0):

Use a HTML iframe to display www.site2.com/Page2.aspx?SiteSource=siteA, e.g.

```
<iframe src="www.site2.com/Page2.aspx?SiteSource=siteA" height="800" width="600" border="0" />
```

[More about the iframe tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp).

Comment: i can't use iframes, because the page internal urls display site2.

Comment: The other answers that involve fetching data from the remote server using some kind of proxy might be more appropriate then.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL doesn't change, it's not a redirect. However, you could create a proxy script that fetches the other page, rewrites any URLs within it, then outputs the result.